# PowerShell understand Get-Member

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem understanding the "Get-Member" Definition column.
I'm doing:

```
$Array = "ans", "zwei","drei"
```

`$Array.GetType()` gives back - as expected - `BaseType=System.Array`

Then:

```
$Array | gm
```

says nothing about a method `Add()` - which is correct since `$Array` is an array.

But:

```
gm -inputobject $Array
```

is showing me an `Add()`-Method, with the definition

```
int IList.Add(System.Object value).
```

Of course: `$Array.Add("vier")` doesn't work.
I know: IList is an interface etc. but it's here completely wrong since we're talking of a variable of an Array-type?

To make the chaos perfect: the intellisense of my ISE (PS Version: 4) is showing the `Add()`-Method as well.

What a mess. How to understand correctly the "definition" column using Get-Member?

Comment: `BaseType` is not the objects own `Type`, but a type that it directly inherits from.

Answer (score 6):

The type of this object:

```
$Array = "ans","zwei","drei"
```

if *not* `System.Array`, but `Object[]` - a type of collection that directly inherits from `System.Array`, but is not the same as.

If you dig a little deeper down the rabbithole, you'll find that the type of `$Array` does in fact implement `IList`:

```
PS C:\> $Array.GetType().ImplementedInterfaces
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ICloneable
True     False    IList
True     False    ICollection
True     False    IEnumerable
True     False    IStructuralComparable
True     False    IStructuralEquatable
True     False    IList`1
True     False    ICollection`1
True     False    IEnumerable`1
True     False    IReadOnlyList`1
True     False    IReadOnlyCollection`1
```

The reason `$Array | gm` doesn't show an `Add()` method is that when you pipe `$Array` to `gm`, the pipeline tries to enumerate the contents of `$Array`, and what `gm` shows you is really the members of the contained type - a `System.String`:

[image]

To get the members of the array object itself instead of those of the array elements you must pass it to `Get-Member` via the `-InputObject` method:

```
PS C:\> Get-Member -InputObject $Array

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name           MemberType            Definition
----           ----------            ----------
Count          AliasProperty         Count = Length
Add            Method                int IList.Add(System.Object value)
Address        Method                System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, C...
Clear          Method                void IList.Clear()
Clone          Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object IClonea...
CompareTo      Method                int IStructuralComparable.CompareTo(System.O...
Contains       Method                bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)
CopyTo         Method                void CopyTo(array array, int index), void Co...
Equals         Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool IStruct...
...
```

Comment: Thanks, makes a perfect sense!

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that `$array | get-member` returns a `System.String` as a type in this case, that string does not have a "Add" method. If your array would be equal to, say, `@(1,2)`, you'll get an output of `System.Int32` as "its" type. The reason on this is that you're using pipelines that are designed to unfurl arrays into cmdlets that normally are designed to perform one action per input member. So, the `get-member -InputObject $array` **is** the proper way of querying arrays for members, and not querying its members for *their* members.

The trick with `$array.Add('vier')` is a tad different - I've just tested and the exception does not say "illegal call", it says "size is fixed", and it is indeed so, `$array.IsFixedSize` returns true. The probable reason for this is to not expose the actual `IList` alteration mechanics and just declare them "fixed size" and only override this limit in operators or methods designed to accept arrays.

UPDATE: As @Mathias says in his answer, the actual type of `$array` is `System.Object[]` which I missed, and by the list of its interfaces, it was designed to declare itself as "read only" to .NET methods on interfaces, so it should only be modified by Powershell code, not .NET code.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. Still one question: why is the intellisense confused and shows after $Array. the method "Add()" as if it would be possible to use it (but it's not)?

Comment: Because the `IList` interface specifies such a method.

Comment: @Purclot Because the implementation exists, and `Get-Member` is not aware about that implementation to always throw errors.

Comment: @Purclot please consider accepting one of the answers (click the grey checkmark below the voting arrows) if you feel it answered your question. The question will no longer figure as "unanswered" and you get +2 rep :)

Answer (score 3):

First: collections are enumerated, when passed by pipeline, so in this case `$Array | gm` `Get-Member` cmdlet does not see an array, but individual items of it, so it report members of items not members of array.

Second: arrays implement `IList` interface, and single dimensions zero-based arrays also implement generic version of that interface. Some interface methods are implemented explicitly, like `Add` or `Contains`.

Consider this code:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    using System;
    public interface IInterface {
        void Method();
    }
    public class Class1:IInterface {
        void IInterface.Method() {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
    public class Class2:IInterface {
        void IInterface.Method() {
            //Do something.
        }
    }
'@
(New-Object Class1).Method()
(New-Object Class2).Method()
([IInterface](New-Object Class1)).Method()
([IInterface](New-Object Class2)).Method()
```

Try run it in PowerShell v2. All `Method` calls failed with error `Method invocation failed because [Class] doesn't contain a method named 'Method'.` It is true, nor `Class1` nor `Class2` have `Method` method. So the problem: how to call interface method if class implement it explicitly?

In PowerShell v3 that changed. All interface methods now also reported as members of object, so call `(New-Object Class2).Method()` works. Problem is that PowerShell does not have a way to know why interface method was implemented explicitly, because it not supported or because it intended to call thru interface, so it have to report `Method` as member for `Class1` and `Class2`, even if `Class1` does not actually support than member.

For example `IList.Contains` is valid call for array but this code:

```
$a=1..10
$a.Contains(5)
```

fails in PowerShell v2:

```
function f{
    param(
        [Collections.IList]$List,
        [Object]$Item
    )
    $List.Contains($Item)
}
$Array=1..10
$List=New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Object] (,$Array)
f $Array 5 #This will fail in PowerShell v2
f $List 5
```