# Why does an empty Powershell hash table evaluate to True when an empty array evaluates to False?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm experimenting with True and False in Powershell 4.0.  Here are the results when looking at an empty array and an empty hash table:

```
PS C:\Users\simon> $a = @()    
PS C:\Users\simon> if ($a) { Write-Host "True" } else { Write-Host "False" }
False

PS C:\Users\simon> $a = @{}    
PS C:\Users\simon> if ($a) { Write-Host "True" } else { Write-Host "False" }
True
```

Why do empty hash tables evaluate to True when empty arrays evaluate to False?

According to the Powershell documentation [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-4.0):

> When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators
>   return any matching values. If there are no matches in a collection,
>   comparison operators do not return anything.

From that I would expect both a hash table and an array to act the same when they are empty, since both are collections.  I would expect both to evaluate to False because they return nothing to the `if` clause.

Comment: A hash table is not a collection of values. It is a collection of dictionary entries that have key and value properties.  I wouldn't expect to be able to use comparison operators against a hash table because it's not a coherent expression. Are you testing for key names or values?

Comment: @mjolinor: At the moment I'm just experimenting.  In the past I've used tests along the lines of `if ($a) { ... }` to check if an array has elements or not.  I assumed I could do something similar with a hash table and was surprised when the hash table exhibited different behaviour.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058391/1701026

Comment: [Related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a question of True/False. You can test this using the Boolean operators `$true` and `$false`. I've used `$h` as the empty hashtable `@{}`

```
PS C:\> $a = @()
PS C:\> $h = @{}
PS C:\> if ($a -eq $true) { Write-Host "True" } else { Write-Host "False" }
False

if ($h -eq $true)    >  False
if ($a -eq $false)   >  False
if ($h -eq $false)   >  False
```

Also not equal to automatic variable `$null`:

```
if($a -eq $null)     >  False
if($h -eq $null)     >  False
```

As per [iRon's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058391/5039142), `Count` is a better test to see if a hashtable/array is empty. [Related `Length`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761715/5039142)

The different behaviour will be related to the fundamental types.

```
PS C:\> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $h.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

---

**It's to do with how the `if` statement works and the `Length` property, [AFAICS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAICS). Below is my (admittedly shaky) understanding from multiple StackOverflow posts and external links.**

---

`Get-Member` behaviour is different - see [Mathias's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30977897/5039142)

```
$a | Get-Member            # Error - Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
$h | Get-Member            # TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable. Has Count method, no Length property
Get-Member -InputObject $a # TypeName: System.Object[]. Has Count method, has Length property
```

The `Length` property of the variables is different. But the hashtable does not have a `Length` property - [see mjolinar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761715/5039142).

```
$a.Length   > 0
$h.length   > 1
```

Combining with [Ansgar's link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) explains the different behaviors in the `if` statement as it seems to be implicitly getting the `Length` property . It also allows us to do this:

```
if ($a.Length -eq $true)    >  False
if ($h.Length -eq $true)    >  True
```

Using the [IsNullOrEmpty method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [String] .Net class gives different output compared to `$null`, I assume because this also relies on the `Length`.

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($a))    > True
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($h))    > False
```